# SCCM - Software update status query in powershell

Tags: powershell, sccm, software-update

I just need to get the specific cmdlet in SCCM powershell on how to display the Article ID, Title and Status on each devices depending on my collection group. I can definitely see it SCCM but i just need to check this via powershell and export the result via .csv

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHkqy.png)

i tried every cmdlet available in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/configurationmanager/get-cmsoftwareupdatecontentinfo?view=sccm-ps and I can't see one. Big help if someone can provide some information on this. Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.